# How to get all ActiveRecord objects in Yii2?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

How can I get all ActiveRecord objects in Yii2 like an array, which can be iterated by `foreach()` .

This is the code which should work but it returns zeros instead of actual data.

```
    public function getAllCategories(){

    $categoriesList=[];

    $categories=  Category::find()->orderBy("id")->all();
    foreach ($categories as $category){

        $categoriesList[]+=$category->title;

    }
    return $categoriesList;


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting your objects, you are still able to iterate through them. Try to make following simple change (look at "+=" change to "0"):

```
public function getAllCategories(){

    $categoriesList = array();

    $categories = Category::find()->orderBy("id")->all();
    foreach ($categories as $category){

        $categoriesList[] = $category->title;

    }
    return $categoriesList;
}
```

Here is some reference to active record in Yii2: [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html). With `find()->all()` you are getting an array with objects.

Answer (score 0):

You have error in Your php syntax - You are using +=, which is not capable to add strings, You should either use just = or .=

Comment: Actually  $categoriesList is an array, so I would not consider the concatenation option, imho.

Comment: from performance side, i see no difference in using both methods, 
    for($i=0; $i<100000; $i++){$a[] .= 'lalalalala';} returns same time for both .= and = Is there any other reason not to use concatenation?

Comment: Yes, it is not logic in this context, since you are working with arrays, and not strings... the fact that it is working doesn't mean it's ok, logically.